# implicit conversion at call by value and polymorphism

Tags: c++, gcc, constructor, polymorphism, implicit-conversion

Consider the following scenario:
Some polymorphic classes:

```
struct iClass 
{
  virtual ~iClass(){} 
};
struct CommonClass : public iClass 
{
  char str[128];
  CommonClass() { ... }
  ...
};
struct SpecificClass : public iClass
{
  char str[32];
  SpecificClass () { ... }
  SpecificClass (SpecificClass& src) { strcpy(...); ... }
  SpecificClass (CommonClass& src) { strcpy(...); ... }
  SpecificClass (const CommonClass& src) { strcpy(...); ... }
  void foo() { ... }
};
```

Furthermore a function:

```
void someFunc(SpecificClass sc) { sc.foo(); } // pass by value: i want it copied!

int main ()
{
  CommonClass comCl;
  someFunc(comCl);  // <- Error: no matching function for call to 'SpecificClass::SpecificClass(SpecificClass)' NOTE: no &
  SpecificClass specCl(comCl);
  someFunc(specCl); // Works normal, but the str gets copied double times this way, isnt it?
  return 0;
}
```

Why does the compiler not allow the conversion from CommonClass to SpecificClass in the first function call although a new SpecificClass gets constructored on the call anyways and there is a constructor for this specific conversion?
And why do i get this strange error message? A call to a copy constructor without a reference?
Can anyone share some insight into this problematic?

Btw, i have to use gcc 4.1.2

Comment: Your constructor takes a `CommonClass &`, but you'd need one that accepts a `const CommonClass &`. As it stands, you are trying to bind an rvalue to a non-const lvalue reference.

Comment: what part do you exactly mean would be an rvalue? i dont see any constants here?

Comment: well i added a const constructor in the specificClass for the commonClass. Still the same error! but now with one more "candidates" ;)

Comment: Yes, you need to use `const SpecificClass &` in the ordinary copy constructor as well.

Comment: [`const`-correctness](http://ideone.com/T3Sv9j).

Comment: To be perfectly precise, you need -- for this particular use case -- `const SpecificClass &` in the copy constructor of `SpecificClass` only. The conversion constructor (i.e. the one that takes a `CommonClass` reference as argument can remain as it is (although I find that unusual.. why not use const-reference there too?)

Comment: ok i works now with the const added to SpecificClass::SpecificClass(const SpecificClass&). Thanks! But i still dont understand why it had to be with this particular constructor? and will only one constructor be called or more?

Comment: Two are called: First the conversion constructor, then the copy constructor. (Whether the latter one will really be called at run-time is matter of optimization by the compiler. But formally, the compiler must pretend that it calls it.)

Comment: As concerns the added `const`: a "standard" copy constructor does _not_ modify its argument, hence takes it by _reference-to-`const`_ (an infamous exception being `std::auto_ptr` (deprecated in C++11)); more important maybe, if omitting the `const` it will not be able to copy from const objects or temporaries. (See jogojapan's answer below)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`someFunc` requires an argument of type `SpecificClass`, and you provide one of type `CommonClass`. Since you have defined a conversion constructor

```
SpecificClass::SpecificClass(CommonClass &)
```

this conversion can be performed implicitly, and that's great so far.

[Note, though, that your conversion constructor takes a non-const reference, which works here because you actually supply it with an lvalue – however, in general, I'd assume that taking the argument of the conversion constructor as `const CommonClass &` is usually better (since the conversion from one type into another isn't usually expected to alter the original).]

However, the *problem* occurs in the next step: The freshly converted object of type `SpecificClass` now needs to be copied into the function argument `sc` of `someFunc`. For this you need a copy constructor for `SpecificClass` which can take an rvalue (that's what the freshly converted `SpecificClass` object is, because it's a temporary).

Your copy constructor

```
SpecificClass::SpecificClass(SpecificClass &)
```

is declared to take a non-const lvalue reference, which can't bind to the temporary. So you must change this into

```
SpecificClass::SpecificClass(const SpecificClass &)
```

to fix the problem. And that's the usual way of declaring a copy constructor anyway.

---

One other thing I can't help noticing: You have a function `someFunc` that is meant to be called on objects of a very specific type only. Yet you call it on a general (base class?) type. Clearly, this can be made to work in the way you described, but it is in many ways counter-intuitive and not well-aligned with the principle of object-oriented programming. It also makes me wonder how the 'specific' object is actually created from the 'common' one, i.e. what the conversion constructor actually does. Intuitively, I'd assume the 'common' object given as input lacks the 'specific' information to create a 'specific' object.

In any case, you may want to reconsider the structure of your class hierarchy and/or the purpose of `someFunc`. None of this is directly related to the problem described in your question, though.

Comment: wonderfull explanation. thanks for insight! Too bad that it was intended that only one constructor gets called in the first place(not by "maybe optimization")! Is there a way to achieve this by using constructors on a function call?

Comment: All of those Classes only hold one c-string each i got from some serial communication device. i look into, identify and pass them to the the apropiate callback function (someFunc) which expect the specific classes where additional specific getter and setter exists, so the values encoded within the string can be manipulated.

Comment: @PhilippMichalski Hmmm. Regearding the optimization (i.e. to make sure only one copy is performed, rather than one for conversion and one for the function call): I might be wrong, but I don't see any way to guarantee this. (I am nevertheless pretty sure that GCC, even 4.1, performs this optimization, at least with `--O2` or `--O3`. The fact that it complains about the missing copy constructor does not mean that it doesn't optimize the code. It complains for formal reasons.)

Comment: Well the "optimization level" of my GCC is actually '--O0' so i cant count on that :-D i dont know why, but its the default value given from the vendor of my PLC and i cant change it. i should ask them sometimes... i assume its because thats their first prototype PLC programmable with c++, which may also explain why it only works with GCC 4.1.2 (or 2.95.3) ...

Comment: Ok... I must say, that's not good if you are after speed. Avoiding this one copy may be the least of your problems in this case. However, you may want to check whether the second copy constructor is called or now (e.g. by adding a print statement into it). If it is, and you don't want that, I am afraid you'll have to make a separate version of `someFunc` for each data type you want to copy. Defining it as a template would help you save some typing, though.